# How to iterate through all 'tr' sections of HTML website using BeautifulSoup package in Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am data scraping an HTML website using the BeautifulSoup package in Python code, looking to get all college basketball team data. My for loop is setup as below and scrapes the data as I want - however, there are multiple 'thead' sections separating the data in the table, and my code appears to be stopping the data scrape when the first 'thead' section of HTML appears beneath the first 40 records of data. As of now, it is only giving me data in the first section of the HTML website code - for reference, there are 362 records of data and I am only getting the first 40 records because of these 'thead' sections that split up the data table. How can I get this code to loop through all the 'tr' sections?

I am scraping the website https://kenpom.com.

Code:

```
for team_kenpom in table_kenpom.find_all('tbody'):
    rows = team_kenpom.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        kenpom_rank = row.find('td', class_ = 'hard_left').text
        school = row.find('td', class_ = 'next_left').text
        conference = row.find('td', class_ = 'conf').text
        record = row.find('td', class_ = 'wl').text
        adjEM = row.find_all('td')[4].text
        adjO = row.find('td', class_ = 'td-left divide').text
        adjO_rank = row.find('td', class_ = 'td-right').text
        adjD = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'td-left')[1].text
        adjD_rank = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'td-right')[1].text
        adjT = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'td-left divide')[1].text
        adjT_rank = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'td-right')[2].text
        luck = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'td-left divide')[2].text
        luck_rank = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'td-right')[3].text
        adjEM_opp = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'td-left divide')[3].text
        adjEM_opp_rank = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'td-right')[4].text
        adjO_opp = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'td-left')[5].text
        adjO_opp_rank = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'td-right')[5].text
        adjD_opp = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'td-left')[6].text
        adjD_opp_rank = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'td-right')[6].text
        adjEM_opp_nonconf = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'td-left divide')[4].text
        adjEM_opp_nonconf_rank = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'td-right')[7].text
```

Output:

````
>>> print(team_list_kenpom)
[
  [
    "1",
    "Connecticut",
    "BE",
    "31-3",
    "+32.21",
    "126.6",
    "1",
    "94.4",
    "11",
    "64.5",
    "329",
    "+.047",
    "70",
    "+10.47",
    "34",
    "111.6",
    "40",
    "101.2",
    "31",
    "-3.35",
    "285"
  ],
  [
    "2",
    "Houston",
    "B12",
    "30-4",
    "+31.72",
    "118.9",
    "17",
    "87.2",
    "2",
    "63.3",
    "348",
    "+.053",
    "61",
    "+11.76",
    "14",
    "111.9",
    "36",
    "100.1",
    "6",
    "-0.78",
    "225"
  ],
  [
    "3",
    "Purdue",
    "B10",
    "29-4",
    "+29.12",
    "125.1",
    "3",
    "96.0",
    "21",
    "67.4",
    "174",
    "+.045",
    "75",
    "+13.75",
    "3",
    "114.0",
    "5",
    "100.2",
    "9",
    "+10.36",
    "13"
  ],
  [
    "4",
    "Auburn",
    "SEC",
    "27-7",
    "+28.90",
    "120.6",
    "10",
    "91.7",
    "4",
    "69.8",
    "58",
    "-.067",
    "324",
    "+9.61",
    "53",
    "111.9",
    "35",
    "102.3",
    "72",
    "+1.45",
    "152"
  ],
  [
    "5",
    "Iowa St.",
    "B12",
    "27-7",
    "+26.72",
    "113.9",
    "55",
    "87.1",
    "1",
    "67.3",
    "179",
    "+.012",
    "155",
    "+10.38",
    "37",
    "111.0",
    "58",
    "100.6",
    "14",
    "-7.19",
    "351"
  ],
  [
    "6",
    "Arizona",
    "P12",
    "25-8",
    "+26.63",
    "121.1",
    "8",
    "94.5",
    "12",
    "71.8",
    "16",
    "-.043",
    "288",
    "+10.81",
    "25",
    "111.9",
    "34",
    "101.1",
    "27",
    "+10.46",
    "10"
  ],
  [
    "7",
    "Tennessee",
    "SEC",
    "24-8",
    "+25.97",
    "117.1",
    "29",
    "91.1",
    "3",
    "69.2",
    "79",
    "-.030",
    "266",
    "+12.63",
    "8",
    "114.3",
    "2",
    "101.7",
    "51",
    "+8.50",
    "21"
  ],
  [
    "8",
    "Duke",
    "ACC",
    "24-8",
    "+24.88",
    "121.8",
    "7",
    "96.9",
    "26",
    "66.7",
    "231",
    "-.077",
    "333",
    "+8.56",
    "75",
    "110.6",
    "72",
    "102.0",
    "64",
    "+0.14",
    "199"
  ],
  [
    "9",
    "North Carolina",
    "ACC",
    "27-7",
    "+24.65",
    "117.8",
    "24",
    "93.1",
    "6",
    "70.4",
    "41",
    "-.024",
    "250",
    "+11.24",
    "21",
    "112.4",
    "21",
    "101.2",
    "32",
    "+7.08",
    "36"
  ],
  [
    "10",
    "Illinois",
    "B10",
    "25-8",
    "+23.78",
    "124.8",
    "4",
    "101.0",
    "81",
    "69.9",
    "57",
    "-.039",
    "285",
    "+10.71",
    "29",
    "111.3",
    "46",
    "100.6",
    "15",
    "-2.25",
    "261"
  ],
  [
    "11",
    "Creighton",
    "BE",
    "23-9",
    "+23.40",
    "120.1",
    "12",
    "96.7",
    "24",
    "67.0",
    "207",
    "-.013",
    "220",
    "+11.15",
    "23",
    "112.2",
    "29",
    "101.0",
    "25",
    "+5.13",
    "69"
  ],
  [
    "12",
    "Marquette",
    "BE",
    "25-9",
    "+22.74",
    "118.3",
    "21",
    "95.6",
    "19",
    "69.0",
    "91",
    "+.036",
    "98",
    "+13.14",
    "7",
    "113.3",
    "6",
    "100.2",
    "8",
    "+8.28",
    "23"
  ],
  [
    "13",
    "Alabama",
    "SEC",
    "21-11",
    "+22.48",
    "125.6",
    "2",
    "103.1",
    "112",
    "72.6",
    "9",
    "-.028",
    "262",
    "+13.67",
    "5",
    "114.5",
    "1",
    "100.8",
    "18",
    "+9.15",
    "18"
  ],
  [
    "14",
    "Baylor",
    "B12",
    "23-10",
    "+22.31",
    "122.5",
    "6",
    "100.2",
    "64",
    "65.6",
    "281",
    "-.004",
    "196",
    "+14.07",
    "1",
    "112.8",
    "12",
    "98.7",
    "1",
    "+3.17",
    "101"
  ],
  [
    "15",
    "Gonzaga",
    "WCC",
    "25-7",
    "+21.56",
    "121.0",
    "9",
    "99.4",
    "47",
    "69.1",
    "83",
    "-.052",
    "301",
    "+3.38",
    "105",
    "108.4",
    "100",
    "105.0",
    "126",
    "+7.51",
    "27"
  ],
  [
    "16",
    "BYU",
    "B12",
    "23-10",
    "+21.01",
    "120.5",
    "11",
    "99.5",
    "48",
    "69.1",
    "85",
    "-.034",
    "273",
    "+9.65",
    "52",
    "110.5",
    "74",
    "100.8",
    "21",
    "-5.49",
    "327"
  ],
  [
    "17",
    "Wisconsin",
    "B10",
    "22-12",
    "+20.78",
    "119.6",
    "13",
    "98.8",
    "39",
    "65.1",
    "307",
    "-.021",
    "241",
    "+13.63",
    "6",
    "112.9",
    "10",
    "99.3",
    "3",
    "+6.23",
    "47"
  ],
  [
    "18",
    "Michigan St.",
    "B10",
    "19-14",
    "+20.03",
    "113.8",
    "57",
    "93.8",
    "8",
    "65.2",
    "305",
    "-.104",
    "355",
    "+12.31",
    "12",
    "114.1",
    "4",
    "101.7",
    "57",
    "+4.49",
    "77"
  ],
  [
    "19",
    "Kentucky",
    "SEC",
    "23-9",
    "+20.02",
    "122.7",
    "5",
    "102.7",
    "108",
    "72.6",
    "11",
    "-.027",
    "258",
    "+9.12",
    "66",
    "111.3",
    "47",
    "102.2",
    "70",
    "-0.18",
    "205"
  ],
  [
    "20",
    "Saint Mary's",
    "WCC",
    "26-7",
    "+19.89",
    "114.9",
    "45",
    "95.0",
    "16",
    "61.9",
    "358",
    "+.020",
    "133",
    "+3.07",
    "108",
    "108.3",
    "105",
    "105.2",
    "133",
    "+5.39",
    "60"
  ],
  [
    "21",
    "San Diego St.",
    "MWC",
    "24-10",
    "+19.70",
    "113.5",
    "62",
    "93.8",
    "9",
    "66.0",
    "266",
    "-.032",
    "268",
    "+11.04",
    "24",
    "112.7",
    "16",
    "101.6",
    "48",
    "+10.70",
    "9"
  ],
  [
    "22",
    "Kansas",
    "B12",
    "22-10",
    "+19.23",
    "113.4",
    "65",
    "94.2",
    "10",
    "68.9",
    "92",
    "+.048",
    "69",
    "+13.73",
    "4",
    "112.9",
    "11",
    "99.1",
    "2",
    "+5.23",
    "64"
  ],
  [
    "23",
    "New Mexico",
    "MWC",
    "26-9",
    "+18.94",
    "115.4",
    "41",
    "96.5",
    "23",
    "72.7",
    "8",
    "-.021",
    "245",
    "+6.85",
    "85",
    "110.2",
    "82",
    "103.3",
    "87",
    "-0.37",
    "212"
  ],
  [
    "24",
    "Texas Tech",
    "B12",
    "23-10",
    "+18.54",
    "117.9",
    "23",
    "99.4",
    "46",
    "66.6",
    "234",
    "+.040",
    "89",
    "+10.54",
    "31",
    "111.3",
    "48",
    "100.8",
    "17",
    "-2.37",
    "263"
  ],
  [
    "25",
    "St. John's",
    "BE",
    "20-13",
    "+18.50",
    "118.4",
    "20",
    "99.9",
    "56",
    "69.2",
    "78",
    "-.068",
    "326",
    "+10.59",
    "30",
    "112.3",
    "24",
    "101.7",
    "54",
    "+1.65",
    "145"
  ],
  [
    "26",
    "Colorado",
    "P12",
    "24-10",
    "+18.47",
    "117.6",
    "25",
    "99.1",
    "43",
    "67.5",
    "165",
    "+.012",
    "156",
    "+8.14",
    "76",
    "110.3",
    "80",
    "102.1",
    "69",
    "-1.50",
    "245"
  ],
  [
    "27",
    "Texas",
    "B12",
    "20-12",
    "+18.40",
    "118.5",
    "19",
    "100.1",
    "60",
    "67.2",
    "196",
    "-.034",
    "272",
    "+10.49",
    "32",
    "111.2",
    "54",
    "100.7",
    "16",
    "-2.96",
    "277"
  ],
  [
    "28",
    "Nebraska",
    "B10",
    "23-10",
    "+18.19",
    "115.9",
    "33",
    "97.7",
    "30",
    "68.6",
    "103",
    "+.014",
    "150",
    "+9.09",
    "68",
    "110.8",
    "64",
    "101.7",
    "52",
    "-5.23",
    "322"
  ],
  [
    "29",
    "Florida",
    "SEC",
    "24-11",
    "+18.19",
    "119.3",
    "14",
    "101.1",
    "84",
    "71.7",
    "18",
    "-.007",
    "202",
    "+10.73",
    "28",
    "112.3",
    "26",
    "101.5",
    "45",
    "+2.06",
    "132"
  ],
  [
    "30",
    "Mississippi St.",
    "SEC",
    "21-13",
    "+17.98",
    "113.7",
    "60",
    "95.7",
    "20",
    "67.1",
    "203",
    "-.044",
    "290",
    "+11.16",
    "22",
    "112.6",
    "18",
    "101.4",
    "39",
    "+0.71",
    "173"
  ],
  [
    "31",
    "Wake Forest",
    "ACC",
    "20-13",
    "+17.79",
    "117.6",
    "26",
    "99.8",
    "55",
    "68.1",
    "133",
    "-.098",
    "354",
    "+8.60",
    "74",
    "110.0",
    "85",
    "101.4",
    "40",
    "-1.81",
    "252"
  ],
  [
    "32",
    "Dayton",
    "A10",
    "24-7",
    "+17.30",
    "118.6",
    "18",
    "101.3",
    "88",
    "64.2",
    "337",
    "+.003",
    "169",
    "+5.95",
    "88",
    "108.7",
    "98",
    "102.7",
    "76",
    "+7.01",
    "38"
  ],
  [
    "33",
    "TCU",
    "B12",
    "21-12",
    "+17.29",
    "115.1",
    "44",
    "97.8",
    "31",
    "69.7",
    "63",
    "-.049",
    "298",
    "+9.83",
    "46",
    "110.6",
    "68",
    "100.8",
    "19",
    "-8.39",
    "357"
  ],
  [
    "34",
    "Clemson",
    "ACC",
    "21-11",
    "+16.94",
    "117.4",
    "27",
    "100.5",
    "67",
    "66.1",
    "260",
    "-.022",
    "246",
    "+10.08",
    "41",
    "112.2",
    "28",
    "102.1",
    "68",
    "+5.20",
    "65"
  ],
  [
    "35",
    "Villanova",
    "BE",
    "18-15",
    "+16.94",
    "111.6",
    "84",
    "94.6",
    "13",
    "63.2",
    "350",
    "-.087",
    "347",
    "+11.33",
    "20",
    "112.7",
    "17",
    "101.3",
    "37",
    "+6.06",
    "48"
  ],
  [
    "36",
    "Nevada",
    "MWC",
    "26-7",
    "+16.81",
    "115.5",
    "40",
    "98.7",
    "36",
    "66.6",
    "233",
    "+.059",
    "53",
    "+5.69",
    "89",
    "109.7",
    "87",
    "104.1",
    "95",
    "-1.10",
    "231"
  ],
  [
    "37",
    "Cincinnati",
    "B12",
    "20-14",
    "+16.72",
    "112.3",
    "77",
    "95.5",
    "17",
    "67.3",
    "188",
    "-.079",
    "336",
    "+9.43",
    "57",
    "110.7",
    "65",
    "101.3",
    "36",
    "-4.01",
    "300"
  ],
  [
    "38",
    "Colorado St.",
    "MWC",
    "24-10",
    "+16.60",
    "115.4",
    "42",
    "98.8",
    "38",
    "65.8",
    "270",
    "-.025",
    "254",
    "+9.16",
    "65",
    "112.1",
    "31",
    "103.0",
    "85",
    "+5.83",
    "52"
  ],
  [
    "39",
    "Boise St.",
    "MWC",
    "22-10",
    "+16.39",
    "114.0",
    "52",
    "97.6",
    "29",
    "66.8",
    "221",
    "+.010",
    "158",
    "+9.32",
    "59",
    "111.0",
    "57",
    "101.7",
    "53",
    "+7.77",
    "26"
  ],
  [
    "40",
    "Pittsburgh",
    "ACC",
    "22-11",
    "+16.36",
    "115.9",
    "35",
    "99.5",
    "50",
    "65.5",
    "292",
    "+.005",
    "166",
    "+7.76",
    "80",
    "110.6",
    "69",
    "102.8",
    "81",
    "-6.29",
    "340"
  ]
]```
````

Comment: Can you add to your question the webpage html you want to scrape?

Comment: `find_all("td")` should give you all your td's irrespective of the `class_` value. But if that picks up those `td`'s that you don't need and only need ones in this list `("hard_left", "next_left", "conf", "wl", "td-left divide", "td-right", "td-left", "td-left divide",)`, you can use `class_=re.compile(r'(hard_left|next_left|conf|wl|td-left divide|td-right|td-left)')` with `find_all("td")` and you're golden

Comment: The webpage I am scraping is https://kenpom.com @halloleo

Comment: @KavinDsouza the find/find_all('td' ...) section of my code is working fine. The question I am trying to have answered is how to iterate through all the 'tr' sections of this webpage's HTML code. There are multiple 'thead' sections that split up the data table every 40 entries (college basketball teams). If you have any insight for tweaking my code to iterate through all these 'tr' sections, that would be much appreciated!

Comment: I am unclear about the problem: using `find_all('tr')` should find all the `tr` elements in the web page, regardless of the `<thead>` sections. Is that not working? How does the content of `team_list_kenpom` differ from what you expect? Please *update your question* with this additional information, rather than leaving it in a comment.

Comment: @larsks I did go back and update my question after responding to some comments, but my apologies if my etiquette is not the best - I am still a relatively new user on Stack Overflow! The content of team_list_kenpom differs from what I expect because the code is not going through all the 'tr' elements. It should give me 362 records, but is only returning the first 40 records (I believe because of the <thead> sections embedded in between the 'tr' elements).

Comment: i was able to use the `find_all("tr")` to get a total of 382 tr tags on the webpage. However, I'd like to point out that I had to use Selenium in order to enable javascript on the browser, and only then did I find the `tr` tags.